# How to find value (%) on Data Frame?

Tags: machine-learning

When I use code:
predictions = lm.predict(Xtest)

give me following error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.01%'

And I don't see any value like this in file. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: double check for values in all the columns in Xtest. There must be '0.01%' in it.

Comment: Check the dtypes of Xtest. Convert to float.